# losing data when using an exported symbol with parameters in linux module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to export a function so that it can be used from an other linux module, the exported function is successfully detected by the second module and can be called, but it looks like I'm using data with the passed parameters.

All the examples I found on the internet are using `void` parameters.

Here are the two modules :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>



static void exported_function(char* buffer, int n) {

  char msg[n];
  copy_from_user(msg, buffer, n);

  printk("MAIN received : %s\n", buffer);
  printk("MAIN copied : %s\n", msg);
  printk("MAIN size(n) : %s\n", n);

}

static int __init load_module(void) {
  printk("module loaded");

  return 0;
}

static void __exit unload_module(void) {
  printk("module unloaded");
}


module_init(load_module);
module_exit(unload_module);

EXPORT_SYMBOL(exported_function);
```

And the second one is :

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

extern void exported_function(char*, int);


int init_module(void) {
  printk("module COMM loaded");

  char* str = "AA";
  exported_function(str, 2);


  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
  printk("module COMM unloaded!");
}
```

After inserting the second module, I get this output via dmesg :

```
[ 2951.103121] module loaded
[ 2951.104417] module COMM loadedMAIN received : AA
[ 2951.104422] MAIN copied : 
[ 2951.104424] MAIN size(n) : (null)
```

As you can see, `n`  in `exported_function(char *buffer, int n)` is null !! but no loss of data in `buffer`

I don't understand why :/

Thanks.

[EDIT]

If I change the signature of `exported_function(char *, int)` to `exported_function(int, int)`  both values are null !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I. In the second module:

```
char* str = "AA";
exported_function(str, 2);
```

`str` is basically `3` characters instead `2` which you are passing to `exported_function`. Change the 2nd argument to `3`.

II: In module one:

```
printk("MAIN size(n) : %s\n", n);
```

here you are printing size of `n` with format specifier being string type `%s`, change to `%d`, you will the right value which you received from module two.

```
printk("MAIN size(n) : %d\n", n);
```

III: `copy_from_user` is actually copies data from user to kernel space with return value being number of bytes which could not be copied on failure and zero on success. Which means you must collect the value returned, in your case it is non-zero a failure copy since you are trying to copy from kernel space.

Synopsis:

```
unsigned long copy_from_user (  void *      to,
                   const void __user *      from,
                         unsigned long      n);
```